# video js init error

Tags: html, html5-video

I use the videojs as a html5 video player. but when the page was load, some errors like(firebug):
    `Video Error Object { originalEvent=Event error, type="error", timeStamp=`

But the video is played normally after this, but I am afraid this will cause some unknown problems.

I use the videojs like:
`<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto"   width="640" height="480" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="movie.mp4 " type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="movie.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
    </video>`

Someone said that add this to htaccess file of /var/www/, or add them to apache httpd.conf file,

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

But it doesn't work yet.
What's the problem?